# robotjs windows+L combination

Tags: reactjs, robotjs

I'm trying to use the RobotJS library to press the Windows key + L key, but I don't know how to point to the Windows key, and I'm not finding any answers online. Can you help me with this?

I've managed to make it work with Alt+Tab and some other combinations like this:

```
function pressAltTab() {
  robot.keyToggle("alt", "down");
  robot.keyTap("tab");
  robot.keyToggle("alt", "up");
}
```

However, when I tried to simulate the Win+L combination using the following code:

```
function pressWindowsL() {
  robot.keyToggle("home", "down");
  robot.keyTap("l");
  robot.keyToggle("home", "up");
}
```

I also attempted to use 'windows' instead of 'home,' but it didn't work either. When I use 'windows,' it throws an error: `Uncaught Error Error: Invalid key code specified`. So, I believe 'home' is the correct term according to the docs, but it's not functioning as expected.

I even tried a simple code like this to verify if there's an issue unrelated to the keyToggle function, but it still doesn't work:

```
robot.keyToggle("windows", "down");
robot.keyToggle("windows", "up");
```

Comment: I don't see "windows" in [the list of supported keys](http://robotjs.io/docs/syntax#keys)... They have [a FAQ](http://robotjs.io/docs/faq#why-is-insert-key-missing-from-the-keyboard-functions) about that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll need the `command` [key code](http://robotjs.io/docs/syntax#keys) as stated in this [Github issue](https://github.com/octalmage/robotjs/issues/396).